# "Open with SceneBuilder" not an option

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I'm trying to open an fxml document with SceneBuilder. I have SceneBuilder installed, as well as e(fx)clipse, and I have set the SceneBuilder executable to the app. However, when I right-click on an fxml document, "Open with SceneBuilder" doesn't show up anywhere, and when I select "Open With" to "Other", I'm not allowed to select it. Is there something I'm forgetting to do? I have already uninstalled and reinstalled both SceneBuilder and e(fx)clipse.

Answer (score 0):

Settings(preferences?) -> JavaFX

There should be an attribute called `Path to SceneBuilder`

Put the path where you have Scene builder installed. and hit `Ok`

Comment: There's nothing called Path to SceneBuilder, just SceneBuilder Executable which is already set to where scenebuilder is installed